# Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT] Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

```js
router.get("/showCollections",(req,res,next)=>{
  console.log("in showCollections");
  
  
  const collectionsNames=[];
  const dataToSend = []

  mongoose.connection.db.listCollections().toArray(function(err, names){
    for(let i=0;i<names.length;i++){
      collectionName=names[i].name;
      if(collectionName.localeCompare("users")!=0){
        // console.log(names[i].name);
        collectionsNames.push(collectionName);
      }
    }
    for (let i = 0;i < collectionsNames.length;i++) {
      mongoose.connection.db.collection(collectionsNames[i], function (err, collection) {
        collection.find({}).toArray(function(err,data){
          dataToSend.push(data[i]);//want to access this array outside the loop to send it as a response to the frontend
          // console.log(data);
        })
      })
      
    }
  })
})
```

i expect to send the data of all my collections stored in mongodb to my frontend
i want to send the dataToSend array as a response but the elements of the array are not accessible outside the loop

Answer (score 0):

You can send a response only once. To send all the data you must store it to some variable before sending a response. If you use for loop you can do something like this:

```js
const collectionsNames = ['col1', 'col2']
const dataToSend = []

for (let i = 0; i++; i < collectionsNames.length) {
  const collection = db.get(collectionsNames[i])
  dataToSend.push(collection)
}

Promise.all(dataToSend).then(data => res.send(data))
```